# How to silence Prometheus Alertmanager using config files?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager, prometheus-operator

I'm using the official [stable/prometheus-operator](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/prometheus-operator) chart do deploy Prometheus with helm.

It's working good so far, except for the  annoying `CPUThrottlingHigh` alert that is firing for many pods (including the own Prometheus' [config-reloaders containers](https://github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator/issues/2171)). This alert is [currently under discussion](https://github.com/kubernetes-monitoring/kubernetes-mixin/issues/108),  and I want to silence its notifications for now.

The Alertmanager has a [silence feature](https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/alertmanager/#silences), but it is web-based:

> Silences are a straightforward way to simply mute alerts for a given
>   time. Silences are configured in the web interface of the
>   Alertmanager.

**There is a way to mute notifications from `CPUThrottlingHigh` using a config file?**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53277194/whats-meaning-the-container-cpu-cfs-throttled-seconds-total-metrics

Comment: @c4f4t0r thanks, I read about the meaning of `cfs` and the `throttle` metric, but the alert itself and its threshold is still controversial and diverges opinions...For now, I just want to silence it without depending on the AlertManager web interface.

Comment: delete the rule for promethues config

Comment: @c4f4t0r The prometheus-operator chart imports the k8s rules/alerts from [kubernetes-mixin](https://github.com/kubernetes-monitoring/kubernetes-mixin/). There is no suitable way to disable only the `CPUThrottlingHigh` rule; it’s all or nothing (via `defaultRules.rules.k8s` helm config parameter)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well, I managed it to work by configuring a hackish [inhibit_rule](https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/configuration/#inhibit_rule):

```
inhibit_rules:
- target_match:
     alertname: 'CPUThrottlingHigh'
  source_match:
     alertname: 'DeadMansSwitch'
  equal: ['prometheus']
```

The `DeadMansSwitch` is, by design, an "always firing" alert shipped with prometheus-operator, and the `prometheus` label is a common label for all alerts, so the `CPUThrottlingHigh` ends up **inhibited forever**. It stinks, but works.

**Pros:**

- This can be done via the config file (using the `alertmanager.config` helm parameter).
- The `CPUThrottlingHigh` alert is still present on Prometheus for
  analysis.
- The `CPUThrottlingHigh` alert only shows up in the
  Alertmanager UI if the "Inhibited" box is checked.
- No annoying notifications on my receivers.

**Cons:**

- Any changes in `DeadMansSwitch` or the `prometheus` label design will break this (which only implies the alerts firing again).

---

**Update:** *My Cons became real...*

The `DeadMansSwitch` altertname [just changed](https://github.com/helm/charts/pull/11617/files#r259125286) in the stable/prometheus-operator 4.0.0. If using this version (or above), **the new alertname is `Watchdog`**.

Comment: To circumvent the changing alertname (`Watchdog`), you could add a recording rule with expression `vector(1)` and use that in the inhibit configuration.

Answer (score 22):

One option is to route alerts you want silenced to a "null" receiver. In `alertmanager.yaml`:

```
route:
  # Other settings...
  group_wait: 0s
  group_interval: 1m
  repeat_interval: 1h

  # Default receiver.
  receiver: "null"

  routes:
  # continue defaults to false, so the first match will end routing.
  - match:
      # This was previously named DeadMansSwitch
      alertname: Watchdog
    receiver: "null"
  - match:
      alertname: CPUThrottlingHigh
    receiver: "null"
  - receiver: "regular_alert_receiver"

receivers:
  - name: "null"
  - name: regular_alert_receiver
    <snip>
```

Answer (score 10):

I doubt there exists a way to silence alerts via configuration (other than routing said alerts to a `/dev/null` receiver, i.e. one with no email or any other notification mechanism configured, but the alert would still show up in the Alertmanager UI).

You can apparently use the [command line tool `amtool`](https://github.com/prometheus/alertmanager/blob/master/README.md#amtool) that comes with alertmanager to add a silence (although I can't see a way to set an expiration time for the silence).

Or you can use the API directly (even though it is not documented and in theory it may change). According to [this prometheus-users thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/prometheus-users/yHqNP374_fY) this should work:

```
curl https://alertmanager/api/v1/silences -d '{
      "matchers": [
        {
          "name": "alername1",
          "value": ".*",
          "isRegex": true
        }
      ],
      "startsAt": "2018-10-25T22:12:33.533330795Z",
      "endsAt": "2018-10-25T23:11:44.603Z",
      "createdBy": "api",
      "comment": "Silence",
      "status": {
        "state": "active"
      }

}'
```

Comment: thanks for the tips. Routing to `/dev/null` not works for me because I join all firing alerts together to receive them in a single Slack message (like [this](https://engineering.infinityworks.com/slack-prometheus-alertmanager/#step-three---alertmanager-configuration)). I created a hackish inhibit_rule to managed it by config file. Please, read my answer and give me your thoughts if you can :)

Answer (score 1):

You can silence it by sending your alerts through [Robusta](https://github.com/robusta-dev/robusta). (Disclaimer: I wrote Robusta.)

Here is an example:

```yaml
- triggers:
  - on_prometheus_alert: {}
  actions:
  - name_silencer:
      names: ["Watchdog", "CPUThrottlingHigh"]
```

However, this is probably **not** what you want to do!

Some `CPUThrottlingHigh` alerts are spammy and can't be fixed like [the one for metrics-server on GKE.](https://github.com/robusta-dev/alert-explanations/wiki/CPUThrottlingHigh-on-metrics-server-(Prometheus-alert)).

However, in general the alert is meaningful and can indicate a real problem. [Typically the best-practice is to change or remove the pod's CPU limit.](https://github.com/robusta-dev/alert-explanations/wiki/CPUThrottlingHigh-(Prometheus-Alert)).

I've spent more hours of my life than I care to admit looking at `CPUThrottlingHigh` as I wrote an automated playbook for Robusta which analyzes each `CPUThrottlingHigh` and recommends the best practice.